# strange Unity behaviour in fresh install

Tags: unity

After installing natty on my MacBook Pro - fresh install, not an upgrade.  I was happy that almost everything works.  However, my second day in, unity is beginning to become more and more flaky.  If totally crashed on me once - (Unity not Natty - I could still use the apps that were running, just couldn't access the launcher or panel).

Sometimes the launcher becomes misaligned with the mouse - it appears higher on the screen like it is shifted upward, you can click it, but the mouse still thinks it is in the same position so you end up opening a different application that the one you click on - FRUSTRATING!  A restart fixes this problem - but it has happened twice.  Also, the top panel has started to show strange check patterns occasionally. I have a picture of the panel, but the forum won't let me post it here...sigh

Also, sometimes when I enter the search window for applications - I can't type into the search box.

MacBook Pro 7-1
Typical software installs - Shutter, GIMP, LibreOffice, BackInTime, WINE for FirstClass

What might cause this - I kind of like unity when it works...is there something wrong with my graphics setup?   The Additional Drivers application shows Nvidia is installed but 'not in use'....Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first port of call should be **filing a bug**. Run `ubuntu-bug unity` from a terminal and file it on Launchpad (just follow the prompts).

And to save you from restarting, firing off `unity --replace` or `compiz --replace` should restart Unity without needing to restart the whole computer.

Additional Drivers saying "not in use" is a known bug. It's not always accurate.

Comment: Thanks for the command line to restart unity - I thought there must be an easier way.  I did use "ubuntu-bug unity"  - but it gave a message window that said natty was 'no longer in development' and directed me to these forums (it also gave an option for a paid help service)...I'll try again...

Comment: Yeah there's a "Yes, I have gone through technical support, and they have referred me here" option. [Screenshot](http://imgur.com/7pTyE.png)

Comment: Is there another way to restart unity?  'unity --replace' works but it leaves the terminal window running.  When I close the terminal Unity quits too and I'm left with no way to get it back - only the  cursor, no ability to start any applications or new even a new terminal.  

Am I doing something incorrectly?

Thanks for any suggestions you can make...

btw - my unity problem seems to be tied to WINE - some of my wine apps make unity act very strangely...